# how to read variable in assign message policy in APIGee

Tags: apigee

In Apigee

given a variable in javascript policy, example: var value = 123;

how to get this variable in the assign message policy?

by using {a} in the payload message is not reachable

Comment: JS context.setVariable("_flow.myValue", value);

Assign Message: 

<AssignMessage continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="add-formparams-3">
  <Add>
    <FormParams>
      <FormParam name="lang">{_flow.myValue}</FormParam>
    </FormParams>
  </Add>
  <AssignTo transport="http" type="request"/>
</AssignMessage>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the variable to be available for use in any Apigee policy, you first have to make it a flow variable. You can use Apigee's JavaScript Object Model method called `context` to to this (see ref [here](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/javascript-object-model#contextobjectreference-contextobjectmethods)). In your JS policy, you have `var {some-value} = 123;`. To make this available as a flow variable,introduce this line in your JS policy after the variable assignment: `context.setVariable("preferred-variable-name", some-value);`

You can now access this `preferred-variable-name` in your AM policy as show below:

```
<AssignVariable>
    <Name>preferred-variable-name</Name>
    <Ref>preferred-variable-name</Ref>
</AssignVariable>
```

Just to mention it is possible to pass the value directly in the policy as well as shown below

```
<AssignVariable>
  <Name>variable_name</Name>
  <Value>123</Value>
</AssignVariable>
```

Read more [here](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/assign-message-policy#assignvariable-value).

The `<Name>` tag can be set to any name.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the variable in the context object using **context.setVariable("variable-name", value);**

Refer to this variable in the assign_message policy using {variable-name}.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the context variable in jsPolicy like this:

```
context.setVariable("a","123");
```

You can use it after in any of the policies.

Ex :-

```
<QueryParams>
    <QueryParam name="a">{a}</QueryParam>
</QueryParams>
```